# CSS pseudo after underline with floats

Tags: css

I have an underline for headings created with pseudo :after elements, when this heading is displayed to the right of a floated image/div, the underline is shifted over the image/div.

```
h2:after {
   content: '';
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100px;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  background: #0073ae;
}
```

Here's a short codepen explaining it: http://codepen.io/costelc/pen/GqgdvB

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Floats are out-of-flow, so this is expected. If you don't want the header to overlap the float, you should establish a block formatting context.

A common way is setting `overflow` to anything but `visible`, e.g.

```css
h2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

From [CSS 2.1 Floats](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats),

> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created
>   before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not
>   exist.
>
> The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an
>   element in the normal flow that establishes a new [block formatting
>   context](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) (such as an element with `overflow` other than `visible`)
>   must not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block
>   formatting context as the element itself

```css
body {
  max-width: 300px;
}
.right {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.left {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
h2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
h2:after {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100px;
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  background: #0073ae;
}
```

```html
<h2>Good heading here</h2>
<div class="right"></div>
<h2>Another good heading here</h2>
<p>anything here</p>
<br class="clear">
<div class="left"></div>
<h2>Bad heading here</h2>
<p>anything here</p>
```

Comment: Correct. This solves the problem on large devices when there's space. But on responsive, when there's not enough space this breaks the float completely, the image comes over the heading, I've adjusted the codepen here: http://codepen.io/costelc/pen/GqgdvB  Any ideas?